# Is it possible to access a COM Object from Linux

Tags: php, com, office-2003

Office is running in Wine, meaning I have a running Version (2003).

But when I try to create a new COM object I just get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found

```
<?php
$com = new COM('Word.Application');
$com->close();
```

Is there a way to get this working without installing Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run PHP under Wine as well, or have some sort of program running under Wine that can act as a proxy.

Comment: do you know any programm that could do something like that? (I do not want to run php under wine...)

Comment: I do not. You might be able to whip up some XML-/JSON-RPC proxy though.